# Helpful Flags count not consistent

Tags: support, flags

I notices that the "Helpful flags" count in the tracker for batch **Marshal** and the count in the Impact section are not same.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `Marshal` subtracts *declined* flags from it's total -- the "X helpful flags" on the sidebar doesn't.

Comment: I think the count on the impact section also does not count the declined flags. Also if the flag is declined it wont be helpful.

Comment: It doesn't count them, no, but a) I didn't say it did, and b) it doesn't subtract them from the total either. So you have 150 flags that have been marked helpful, and 10 that have been declined.

Comment: Alternatively, it's cacheing.

Comment: Ok I'll check after some time

Comment: Looks like the 140 is cached... 150 is actually the correct net helpful total...

Comment: I would blame [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As most of the comments stated, caching was cause of the issue. I <strike>disabled cache with chrome dev tools then</strike> refresh the page now both the counts are 150.

[image]

**Update**

It was not the client cache, it was caching in the server side. So the cache was updated on the server side. Thanks to [Matt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt) for pointing it out.

Comment: FWIW, disabling your browser cache would have made no difference. These values are cached *on the server*, not by your browser.

Comment: Oh I thought it was local cache.